# Read video frames from bytes - Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, flask, video-streaming

I'm trying to read the video frame from bytes which i sent from client webcam. I want to read this frame without writing to file.

Client Side Code

```
 if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then(function (stream) {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
            var media = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType: 'video/webm'});
            media.ondataavailable = function (e) {
                socket.emit('image', e.data);
            }
            media.start(500)
            //var blob = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            //socket.emit('image', blob);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
            console.log("Something went wrong!");
        });
    }
```

Server Side :

```
@socketio.on('data')
def image(data):
        # the data looks like 'b'\x1aE\xdf\xa3\xa3B\x86\x81\'
```

Comment: What do you mean by “read the frame”? Are you asking about decoding?

Comment: Yes. I need to decode the bytes and pass it as input to cv2.videoCapture(). @szatmary

Comment: Now I'm writing these bytes to file and reading it for processing. Is there any way to process these video bytes without writing?